# How to find largest sequence of a given number in excel?

Tags: excel, sequence

I have a column of zeros and ones

```
1
0
0
0
1
1
```

I want to find out the largest sequence of zeros I have in my column AND how many times it appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1=1,0,1)
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=0,1+B1,0)
```

and copy down:

[image]

the longest sequence is:

```
=MAX(B:B)
```

and the number of times it occurs is:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,D1)
```

if the *MAX()* formula is in **D1**

Comment: I would add that you can also filter on A for 0s and then on B and choose the maximum value.  This will show you the places where the maximum occurs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Very good idea!..............We could also use *VLOOKUP()* to find that first maximum.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid a helper column you can use this "array formula" in C1 for the maximum consecutive zeroes, assuming data in A2:A100

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A100=0)*(A2:A100<>""),ROW(A2:A100)),IF(A2:A100=1,ROW(A2:A100))))`

And this formula in C2 for the number of instances

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A100=0)*(A2:A100<>""),ROW(A2:A100)),IF(A2:A100=1,ROW(A2:A100)))=C1,1))`

Both formulas need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I'm assuming you will have continuous data from A2 with only blanks at the end, perhaps