# How can I count cells in a row but only count adjacent cells once in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have an spreadsheet with the following structure:-

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

I need help to figure out a formula or VBA function, to calculate the Activity Block Count column.

This is the count of non blank, contiguous cells in the date columns. For example Project 5 has 4 weeks of activity but only 3 continuous blocks of activity.

Any idea warmly welcomed ;-). I'm working at the weekend and it's driving me insane!

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Are those typed values or formulas returning the weekly numbers?

Comment: Week Count is a formula =count(range of columns with dates) and Activity Block Count is just a typed in value that I'd like to replace with a  formula or function. Dates across the top will be in date order but may not be sequential. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I meant the numbers in the weeks like 120,987 or 23,184.

Comment: they're just values, not formula results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just walk through the cells in the range, noting changes in whether the cell(s) are populated or not.

```
Function countActivityBlock(rng As Range) As Long

    Dim r As Range, bNum As Boolean

    If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(1)) Then
        bNum = True
        countActivityBlock = 1
    End If

    For Each r In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(r) And Not bNum Then
            bNum = Not bNum
            countActivityBlock = countActivityBlock + 1
        ElseIf IsEmpty(r) And bNum Then
            bNum = Not bNum
        End If
    Next r

End Function
```

[image]

---

<sub>SpecialCells(xlCelltypeConstants, xlNumbers) does not work within a UDF.</sub>

Comment: just returns 1 if I use the formula =countActivityBlock(E8:Q8) in any row. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this isn't going to work. The blank cells are being read as xlNumbers, something I didn't anticipate. I'll run a few more tests.

Comment: This works in a sub or the Immediate window but apparently not within a UDF.

Comment: ok cool - thanks! I was trying to loop through the cells in the range but can't define the logic for a running count that doesn't count cells if they have a value but are adjacent to another cell with a value

Comment: See revision above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176918/discussion-between-jonathan-lyon-and-jeeped).

Answer (score 0):

The formula way of doing this is using FREQUENCY as follows

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:P2<>"",COLUMN(D2:P2)),IF(D2:P2="",COLUMN(D2:P2)))>0))
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633434/how-to-find-largest-sequence-of-a-given-number-in-excel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653509/calculating-frequecy-min-max-average-of-order-placement-in-excel/50658368#50658368)

[image]