# Find streak in a row in Excel

Tags: excel

I have thousands of rows in Excel. In six columns I have percentage values.
For example: [68%][92%][72%][109%][55%][86%]

In these rows I would like to find the longest streak, from the RIGHT, of values that are below or higher than 100%

[68%][92%][72%][109%]**[55%][86%]**     Streak is 2 below 100% -> Below 2

[62%][101%][43%][65%][78%]**[111%]**   Streak is 1 above 100% -> Above 1

[89%][108%][55%]**[114%][111%][120%]** Streak is 3 above 100% -> Above 3

[---][---][---][---]**[147%][154%]**        Streak is 2 above 100% -> Above 2

[---][---][---][---][---]**[45%]**        Streak is 1 below 100% -> Below 1

[116%]**[58%][89%][66%][33%][74%]**     Streak is 5 below 100% -> Below 5

Didn't quite find what I was looking for in "Calculate current streak in Excel row"
[Calculate current streak in Excel row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493560/calculate-current-streak-in-excel-row)

COUNTIF($KJ2341:$KO2341;"<1")
This gives me the total number that are below 1 but I only look for streak from right.

Can you help please?

Comment: Are those cells `[---]` empty?

Comment: Yes, those are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you want to group any that are exactly `100%` with the `above` group. If that is not the case, please specifically state how you want that handled.

Here is one method, assuming the sixth column always has the defining entry:

*Note that if your data starts in columns other than `A`, modification to the formula may be required*

***Edit: Formula changed to handle partially filled rows***

```
=IF(F1>=1,"Above ","Below ") &  IFERROR(COLUMNS($A:$F)- LOOKUP(2,1/IF(F1>=1,A1:F1<1,A1:F1>=1),COLUMN($A:$F)),COUNT(A1:F1))
```

[image]

If the sixth column is not always the last entry, formula solution still possible; but easier if you have Office 365.

- `F1 > 1` determines if we are looking for a streak of aboves or belows
- `A1:F1>1` (or `<=1`) creates an array of appropriate `{TRUE,FALSE}` depending on meeting the condition.
- `1/(the array)` changes it to an array of `{1,DIV/O}`
- `LOOKUP(2,the_array,array of column_numbers)` returns the column number matching the last `TRUE` in the original array we set up.
- Then it's just simple subtraction, with an `IFERROR` to handle the situation where there is only a single entry in the streak.
- If the formula returns an error, then it will be the case that all entries are the same (or blank); so we can just use a slightly different formula in the event of an error.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the support!

Column starts in KJ so I added 295+ in order to get the correct values.

That worked for all cases except when all 6 numbers were below or above 100%

Also, when there was the case of empty cells it didn't get it right I'm afraid.

IF(KO2340>=1;"Above ";"Below ") & 295+COLUMNS(KJ2340:KO2340)-IFERROR(LOOKUP(2;1/IF(KO2340>=1;KJ2340:KO2340<1;KJ2340:KO2340>=1);COLUMN($KJ2340:$KO2340));COLUMNS($KJ2340:$KO2340)-1)

Comment: @Lookingforexperts Sorry about that. But your observations about "all 6" makes sense. I won't be able to get back to this until this evening or tomorrow AM. Out of town and away from a computer right now.

Comment: @Lookingforexperts Formula edited and I think it should handle those situations correctly now. If it does not, please provide the data, the output from the formula, and the expected output.

Comment: Was out of town myself :) 
It works!

IF(KO2345>=1;"Above ";"Below ") &  IFERROR(COLUMNS($KJ:$KO) -LOOKUP(2;1/IF(KO2345>=1;KJ2345:KO2345<1;KJ2345:KO2345>=1);COLUMN($KJ:$KO))+295;COUNT($KJ2345:$KO2345))

Me adding 295 due to not starting in A. Great help!