# How to check if subsequent non-empty cells contains the same value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to count if in the column there are N subsequent elements of a certain value (in this example it's 1). So for the below example, it should return true for A, but false for B. Empty cells shall be ignored.

```
  A   B
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 
| 1 | 1 |  
|   |   |
| 1 | 2 |  
|   | 1 |
+---+---+
| Y | N | <-- RESULT
+---+---+
```

Ideally would be if I could mark all of those 4 or more subsequent cells.

Comment: So you want the result to be ```Y``` if all the cells in that column have the same value (ignoring those left blank) right?

Comment: not exactly - I would like to have Y if from all values in the column there is exactly N (in my case 4) that occurs after each other, at the same time ignoring empty cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this one as well - you need to pull it across for columns B, C etc.

```
=ArrayFormula(max(frequency(if(filter(A:A,A:A<>"")=1,sequence(count(A:A)),""),if(filter(A:A,A:A<>"")<>1,sequence(count(A:A)),"")))>=4)
```

[image]

So how does this work? It goes all the way back to @Barry Houdini, who as far as I know was the first to post [this elegant method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633434/how-to-find-largest-sequence-of-a-given-number-in-excel/30637982#30637982) to find the longest sequence of repeated values within a range in Excel.

It uses Frequency. Frequency counts the number of values which fall within a series of bins defined by cut points

```
Frequency(<Values>,<Cut points>)
```

So if your cut points were 10,20,30 and your values were 12,15,25,35,36,37 you would expect the counts to be 2,1 and 3.

@Barry's insight was to realise that if you made the row numbers for values that you *didn't* want to count be the cut points and the row numbers for values you *did* want to count (in this case 1) be the values, then you could use Frequency to count up the number of consecutive values of interest. This led him to this formula (in his case looking for consecutive zeroes bounded by ones):

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A100=0)*(A2:A100<>""),ROW(A2:A100)),IF(A2:A100=1,ROW(A2:A100))))
```

which is easily adapted for the present situation simply by changing 0 to 1 and 1 to <>1, filtering out the blanks and using Sequence instead of row number.

Comment: Hi @TomSharpe ! Could you please provide a brief explanation of how your formula is working to solve the user's question? Thanks !

Comment: Yes, pleased to do so. Will add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(REGEXMATCH(""&
 IF(A1:B6="", 1, A1:B6), "1"))), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B6), 1)^0))/ROWS(A1:B6)=1, "Y", "N"))
```

[image]